# R error from a beginner: Can't knit, "same length as vector."

Tags: r, vector

I am a major noob at R and have little to no idea what I'm doing, I'm just using R for a class and am trying to knit an assignment however whenever I do so, I continually receive the following:

> Error in names(id.var) <- labels : 'names' attribute [155] must be the same length as the vector [131]

It says this is a problem on line 97, which is this:

```
influencePlot(model2.lm, id.n=5, labels=newfile$iso3c)
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Does this run in a regular ´R´ session, not using `knitr`? Could you post more of the relevant code?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. `lm` likely removes any terms that have `NA`, (consider looking at `str(model2.lm)`). As a result you need to index the vector you are supply to the labels argument by any data in the model where there are `NA` terms. I cannot provide an answer since you haven't provided a reproducible example but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: You should tell us where `influencePlot` comes from (the library call) and in general try to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign labels to a vector where the labels  lengths is greater than vector length. Which is same as:

```
id.var <- seq(1,133,1)
labels <- sprintf("abc[%s]",seq(1:155))

Error in names(id.var) <- labels : 
  'names' attribute [155] must be the same length as the vector [133]
```

Comment: And the solution is probably to use `labels = expand.model.frame(model2.lm, "iso3c")$iso3c`.